# pandas: Groupby with expanding apply and conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to do an expanding min over one column, while following a condition based on another column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'_id': ['a','a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
                   'account': [1,2,3,2,5], 
                   'status':[3, 1, 5, 2, 7]})

  _id  account  status
0   a        1       3
1   a        2       1
2   a        3       5
3   a        2       2
4   a        5       7
```

The rows are chronologically ordered from oldest to newest and show when a user `_id` makes a `status` change to `account`. So here we can see that user `a` marked account `2` with `status` 1 at some point in time, then updated that value later to `2`.

I need a `status_hist` column that shows the global status of all of `a`'s accounts, where global status is defined as the `min` of all existing statuses. At index `0` there is only one status, so the `status_hist` is 3, at index `1` there are now two status', and `status_hist` is 1, and so on. When we get to index `3`, the global status should change from `1` to `2`, since the status `account` `2` has now changed.

I can do this easily with `df.itertuples()`, but would like to avoid doing so if there is a faster approach. Here is the itertuples solution if that helps to clarify what I'm after:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for _, group in df.groupby('_id'):
    res = []
    statuses = defaultdict()
    for row in group.itertuples():
        statuses[row.account] = row.status
        res.append(min(statuses.values()))

    group['status_hist'] = res
    df2 = df2.append(group)
```

which gives:

```
  _id  account  status  status_hist
0   a        1       3            3
1   a        2       1            1
2   a        3       5            1
3   a        2       2            2
4   a        5       7            2
```

thanks if you can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on the column 'account', multiply by the `values` from 'status'. Then use `mask` to replace the 0 with nan to be able to `ffill` per group of '_id', for finally take the `min` over the columns such as:

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.account)*df.status.values[:,None]
df['status_hist'] = df_dummies.mask(df_dummies.eq(0)).groupby(df._id).ffill().min(axis=1)
print (df)
  _id  account  status  status_hist
0   a        1       3          3.0
1   a        2       1          1.0
2   a        3       5          1.0
3   a        2       2          2.0
4   a        5       7          2.0
```